# How to get a random pixel in C#

Tags: c#

If I have a bitmap, I split it into blocks by 3*3 and I want to take randomly a pixel, but if in block he finds a pixel with white color (R.G.B. >175- that's not pure white) I want to take the closest colored pixel (RGB <175), In this case, it's not so randomly. The main idea is to search in every block if there are white pixels and if not to take one randomly, and if he finds one, take the closest colored pixel. I put also the problem, that if in a block are only white pixels, then he must search in the closest colored pixels from blocks in the neighborhood.

```
for (int X = 0; X < Bitmap.Width - 3; X += 3)
        {
            for (int Y = 0; Y < Bitmap.Height - 3; Y += 3)
            {
                Color pix = Bitmap.GetPixel(X, Y);
                    for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                    {
                        for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
                        {
                            int a = random.Next( Bitmap.Width );
                            int b = random.Next( Bitmap.Height );

                            Color rndcolor = bitmap.GetPixel( a, b );
                            if (rndcolor.R >175 && rndcolor.G >175 && rndcolor.B >175)
                            {       \\I don't know how to write the condition to take the closest colored pixel
                            }
                         }
                     }
                 }
            }
```

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the bitmap? If so, I'd imagine that you could first perform some form of flood-fill of the "white" pixels, using the reverse of whatever rules you'd like to use (but you haven't specified in the question) to define "nearest". Then in this loop you'd no longer have to worry about the "white" pixels.

Comment: To take "the closest coloured pixel", you need to search for it; iterate the surrounding pixels until you find the one you want. How exactly you do the search is up to you and your requirements. There's no "search for closest coloured pixel" method in `Bitmap`. As a side-note, `GetPixel` is very slow, so make sure it doesn't make everything unusable :)

Comment: Just don't use `GetPixel` at all. It is far too slow to call more than once. Call `LockBits`, copy the bitmap's bits into an array, read the bits you want from there, and then call `UnlockBits`.

Comment: I know that is no search for "closest coloured pixel" bacause I don't know how to write, If I found one search for the next,if is "white", then next and so on...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Firstly I searched for all "white ones" and he finds all of them.So, I need to "eliminate" all white ones and then split in blocks to search the colored ones ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to search for your colored pixel with some radius and I think it can be done in this way:

```
    int searchRadius = bitmap.Width / 4;
    for (int X = 0; X < bitmap.Width - 3; X += 3)
    {
        for (int Y = 0; Y < bitmap.Height - 3; Y += 3)
        {
            Color pix = bitmap.GetPixel(X, Y);
            for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
            {
                for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
                {
                    int a = random.Next(bitmap.Width);
                    int b = random.Next(bitmap.Height);

                    Color rndcolor = bitmap.GetPixel(a, b);
                    if (rndcolor.R > 175 && rndcolor.G > 175 && rndcolor.B > 175)
                    {
                        int minR = 255;
                        int minG = 255;
                        int minB = 255;
                        Point findedPoint = new Point();
                        for (int X1 = X- searchRadius; X1 < (X + searchRadius)% (bitmap.Width - 3); X1 += 3)
                        {
                            for (int Y1 = 0; Y1 < (Y + searchRadius) % (bitmap.Height - 3); Y1 += 3)
                            {
                                Color searchColor = bitmap.GetPixel(a, b);
                                if (Math.Abs(searchColor.R - rndcolor.R) < minR &
                                    Math.Abs(searchColor.B - rndcolor.B) < minB &
                                    Math.Abs(searchColor.G - rndcolor.G) < minG)
                                {                                                                                    
                                    minR = Math.Abs(searchColor.R - rndcolor.R);
                                    minB = Math.Abs(searchColor.B - rndcolor.B);
                                    minG = Math.Abs(searchColor.G - rndcolor.G);
                                    findedPoint.X = X1;
                                    findedPoint.Y = Y1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Where findedPoint.X and findedPoint.Y will be the coordinates of your color

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need to do is cache (save) the R, G, and B values for the pixel you want something "close" to. Then, iterate through neighboring pixels (progressively "outwards"), comparing their R, G, and B values to your cached values. Use a basic difference comparison, by subtracting the actual value from the target value. Pick the one that's closest (gives the smallest difference).

Note that if you actually want to get good results from a color comparison, you need to do it in a color space other than RGB. Convert the color from RGB to something like [HSV or HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), and use that for the color comparison.

If you want to stick with RGB, you will need to use a formula that maps the red, green, and blue color component values into the way humans actually perceive color, like the [relative luminance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance):

```
Y = 0.2126*red + 0.7152*green + 0.0722*blue
```

You can then just compare the `Y` values of each pixel.

Answer (score 0):

> how to write the condition to take the closest colored pixel

If you have a pixel, and you want the closest colored pixel, you need to iterate over all pixels of interest and find the one whose color has the smallest *distance* from the pixel you have.

To iterate over all pixels of interest:

```
for( int x = minx;  x <= maxx;  x++ )
    for( int y = miny;  y <= maxy;  y++ )
    {
        ... pixel of interest is at x,y
    }
```

One way to find the distance between two colors j and k is to calculate their *Euclidean Distance*, as follows:

```
r = Math.Pow( j.R - k.R, 2.0 );
g = Math.Pow( j.G - k.G, 2.0 );
b = Math.Pow( j.B - k.B, 2.0 );
d = Math.Sqrt( r + g + b );
```

However, if all you are going to do with the Euclidean Distances is compare them, then you can skip the `Sqrt` part and just say `d = r + g + b;`